# I need Solution for input validation on angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Allow :** Only Alphabets, combination of Alphabets & Numbers, combination of Alphabets & Special chars, combination of Alphabets, Numbers & Special chars.
**Don't allow :** Only Numbers, only Special chars, combination of Numbers & Special chars.

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code** that isn't working as expected after you have done all appropriate research

Comment: /^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/ this is the regular exp what i have tried but its not working well

Comment: Add that to the question with a  proper problem description not just *"not working well"* which is virtually meaningless